# how to get the directory names for every file?

Tags: python, file, os.walk

```
root
--- audi    (dirs)
           ---11 01012020.csv  (files)
           ---01 102020.csv
--- bmw
            ---66  10052020.csv
            ---43  11112020.csv
--- mercedes
             ---34  21062020.csv
             ---23  30112020.csv
```

Above is the structure of my root, dirs and paths. Im trying to get 3 things. `car`, `file_id` and `date`.

1. `Car` is the name of the directory
2. `file_id` is the first split( aka
   everything before the 1st whitespace in the filename)
3. `date` is everything after the
   first whitespace in the filename..

This is my code:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path_root):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.csv'):
            file_id = file.split()[0]
            date = re.search(' (\d+).', file).group(1)
            car = ? idk how to get this one.
```

As you can see I managed to get `file_id` and `date`. Now I want to get the car name (name of directroy) for every file... what is the easietst way to achieve that?

Comment: Did you try to print / use the last part of `root`? that is the directory you are in ...

Comment: @PatrickArtner What do you mean? Will that give me the dir name  for every file?

Comment: Why do you expect anything else?

Comment: The full path for your file is `os.path.join(root,file)` - so using the methods from the dupe will give you your directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `root` variable contains the current directory; you want the last component of that for the car.

```py
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path_root):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.csv'):
            file_id = file.split()[0]
            date = re.search(' (\d+).', file).group(1)
            car = os.path.basename(root)
```

If your file names are representative, you don't really need a regex to pull out the date.  Maybe `file.split()[1].split('.')[0]`

Comment: `AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'file'`. I think something is wrong... it doesnt work yet..

Comment: Sorry, fixed now -- I have no idea where that typo came from.